# How to retrieve the keys which have false values in the below mentioned json in angular 5 or typescript

Tags: json, typescript, object, angular5

How to retrieve the keys which have false values in the below mentioned json?

```
xyz: any = {
    abc: {
      'a': true,
      'b': true,
      'c': true,
      'd': false,
      'e': {
        'f': true,
        'g': false
      },
      'h': true,
      'i': true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not the prettiest but it will give you back all the keys which value is false.

```js
xyz = {
    abc: {
      'a': true,
      'b': true,
      'c': true,
      'd': false,
      'e': {
        'f': true,
        'g': false
      },
      'h': true,
      'i': true
    }
}

function getFalseValues(obj, out) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(el) {
    if(obj[el] === false){
      out.push(el);
    }
    if (typeof obj[el] === "object") {
      getFalseValues(obj[el], out);
    }
  });
}

let output = [];
getFalseValues(xyz, output);

console.log(output);
```